# Jasmine test case for angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am new to jasmine and stuck at few places while mocking the functions.
How to mock angular global functions such as `angular.forEach()`, `angular.isDefined()`, `angular.isUndefined()`.

Answer (score 1):

I typically wouldn't mock these functions as they are so simple - I think that it will be harder to mock them than actually use them. For example, for `angular.forEach`, pass in an array and let it loop through it. For `angular.isDefined`, try different test cases, sometimes passing in something that is defined and sometimes something that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

the way you test whether a function has been called is with a jasmine spy. it varies between the versions of jasmine, but generally it looks like:

```
 it("check if a function was called", function(){
    spyOn(angular, "forEach")

    yourFunction();
    expect(angular.forEach).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

that being said, you generaly shouldn't spy on framework/library global functions as a general rule, because fhey get used internally as well as externally.